# How to check the definitions of Classes in DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, definition

We have an in-house system which is developed with MS Access 2007. It contains a logon form which uses external tables using default workspaces (`DBEngine.Workspaces(0)`).

We found out which class and members are used but cannot figure out which database is defined under `DBEngine.Workspaces(0)` since the definition button is gray-out.

Comment: Is this helpful? `DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).Name`

Comment: @HansUp Sorry, probably it was not clear.. I meant I would like to know how I can check which database is used for DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).

We found out that DBEngine.Workspaces(0) >> User >> UserName but we are struggling with figuring out where Class "User" came from.

Comment: I don't understand.  `DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).Name` will show you the full path of the first database file which is open in that workspace.  If that is not what you want, please clarify what you want instead.  Have you actually tried something like this? ... `MsgBox DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).Name`

Comment: @HansUp I got what you meant. I tested to popup a message box and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBEngine.Workspaces(0)` is a `DAO.Workspace` object.

`DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases` is the collection of databases open within that workspace.  `Debug.Print DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases.Count` will tell you how many databases are open within that workspace.

The first of those databases is `DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)`.  And you can inspect its `.Name` property to get the full path to that database file:

```vb
Debug.Print DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).Name
```

In a comment, you also mentioned `UserName`.  That is a *property* of the workspace, not the database.  You can examine that property:

```vb
Debug.Print DBEngine.Workspaces(0).UserName
```

However, unless you're using Access user-level security, `DBEngine.Workspaces(0).UserName` will be the default user, *"admin"*.  So, in that situation, `UserName` is not very useful.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I could get more ideas of DAO. Actually, we are using user-level-security and I could get the full path of the database file with the message box.